# How to have a UIButton action inside a NavigationController's view call the controllers delegate?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I have my main program with *MainAppDelegate.h,MainAppDelegate.m*.
I have created two custom navigation controllers *ANavController, BNavController* classes and have created added the controllers in **Interface Builder** and assigned my custom classes to the two controllers inside the *MainWindow.xib*

When the application first loads I make it render the first NavControllers and its view in the *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* method:

```
[window addSubView:ANavController.view];
```

This is works fine and loads the first navigation controllers view. My problem is that within the view on each nav controller, inside the *viewDidLoad* method I have created a *UIBarButtonItem* which I add to the right side of the navcontroller.

I'm trying to make this button call an action method defined inside my *MainAppDelegate.m*.

For both of my two custom NavController classes I have set the delegate to MainAppDelegate inside **interface builder.** I try to define buttons like so:

```
[flipButton addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(changeModeAction:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and obviously then inside *MainAppDelegate.m* I have defined a method:

```
-(void)changeModeAction:(id)sender
```

This method should flip the ANavigationController currently in the window to he BNavigationController.

But it obviously crashes on the *addTarget:self.delegate*. What's the proper way to do this?
Basically I'm trying to add a button to the top right of each NavControl which will fire a FLIP page animation, switching to the other NavController and it's stack.

So if you're two levels deep on ANavController and you hit the top right button, it will flip to BNavController and wherever you were last in it's stack. Hitting the button again will flip the page again back to ANavController and you'll still be two levels deep, before you switched to B. Does this make sense?

I think my idea implementation needs some work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for posting this as an answer instead of a comment - my reputation is too low to add comments - but could you please provide the error message?

EDIT: See thread below for details - the problem was that 'self' was not a subclass of UINavigationController and therefore did not have a *delegate* property. Changing this to self.navigationController.delegate worked.

Comment: For _[flipbutton addTarget:self.delegate...]_ I get an **Request for member 'delegate' in something not a structure or union**

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting the NavControl - delegate to MainAppDelegate and not the *view*'s delegate? Where are you calling the addTarget:action:forControlEvents?

Comment: Also, using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] instead of self.delegate should be a workaround for *this specific problem only*.

Comment: Inside interface builder, if I expand (tree view) ANavController we have xViewController (expanded) which contains a UIView. Standard setup. ANavController has it's delegate set to MainAppDelegate. **addTarget:action:forControlEvents** (ie. the button created) is defined inside xViewController during the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: okay, there's the problem: xViewController has no delegate, therefore self.delegate is undeclared. You want to access the .delegate - property of ANavController, for this, you need a reference to ANavController from xViewController, for example by creating an IBOutlet with the Interface Builder.

Comment: WOW! Using **addTarget:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]** worked and it correctly called the right method. I'd like to reference it correctly though? _self.delegate_ and _self.parentViewController.delegate_ all give me the same error **Request for member 'delegate' in something....when trying to Build.

Comment: Philipp, you're saying that inside xViewController I need to create an IBOutlet like: _IBOutlet MyNavigationController *navReference_ and then simply hook it up in Interface Builder and then make it _addTarget:self.navReference.delegate_ and I'm good? :) Trying this now.

Comment: yes, you need ANavController.delegate . Not sure, but  self.navigationController.delegate might do the trick without any additional outlets. Let me know if this works, I'd edit my answer above with the correct solution.

Comment: _self.navigationController.delegate does indeed do the trick w/o any additional IBOutlets! Thank you sir. I tried creating a IBOutlet in IB and hooked it up and synthesized the reference inside xViewController. Then called it via _addTarget:self.navReference.delegate_ and I get _Accessing Unknown 'delegate' component of property_ ? Weird. Would be good to know why but I'm marking this thread as correct. Thanks.

Comment: have you included the anav.h ? The compiler doesn't know that anav has a proprety called "delegate" unless you include it's .h - file.

Comment: yep that was it. :) thanks again Philipp. Works like a charm now.